# "Mismatch between run_config.parameter_binds and all circuit parameters" when executing qiskit circuit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, ParameterVector
p = ParameterVector('p', 58)
sum = [0 for _ in range(58)]

# my code is in here such like
# for i in range(n):
#    ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.rx(p[i], i)

ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.bind_parameters({p: sum})
# instead of the above line, I tried also this below one...
# ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.bind_parameters({p[i]: sum[i] for i in range(58)})

ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.barrier()
ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.measure(range(4), range(4))
print(ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.num_parameters)
ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.decompose().draw('mpl', fold=40)

from qiskit import BasicAer, execute
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
results = execute(ATCQNN_CIRCUIT, backend).result()
a = results.get_counts(ATCQNN_CIRCUIT)
print(a)
```

So I could check there has correct parameter binding[image]

and there has correct circuit drawing.[image]

However, if I tried to execute on basicAer, as I wrote my code, then it makes some error

> 'Mismatch between run_config.parameter_binds and all circuit
> parameters. Parameter binds: [] Circuit parameters:
> [ParameterView([ParameterVectorElement(x[0]), ParameterVec

[image]

Please save me from this one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QuantumCircuit.bind_parameters` method per default returns a copy. You should try modifying your code to either

```
ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.bind_parameters(sum, inplace=True)
```

or

```
bound_circuit = ATCQNN_CIRCUIT.bind_parameters(sum)
```

Note that it is not necessary to pass a dictionary with the parameter vector, but you can just pass the parameter values as list. They will be bound to the vector sorted by index.

Comment: I'm honored... Thank you very much. The second one exactly solved my problem.